# Cannot load LESS into page with webpack

Tags: javascript, less, reactjs, webpack

I can't seem to load my `LESS` into my page using webpack

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: './public/js',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
            { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader' },
            { test: /\.es6$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?stage=0&optional=runtime'},
            { test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader") }
        ],
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', {
                allChunks: true
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

My `app/index.js` contains:

```
'use strict';

let stylesheet = require('./styles/index.less');
let routes = require('./routes.js');
let Router = require('react-router');
let { Handler } = Router;

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(root, state) {
    React.render(<Handler query={ state } path={ state.pathname }/>, document.getElementById('app'))
});
```

`var stylesheet` should take all the `buttons.less` because it contains `@import "buttons.less";`

This is the `reactjs` component I am trying to load:

```
var React = require('react');
var { RouteHandler } = require('react-router');

var UserMenu = React.createClass({

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="login-btn">
                    <a href="/login">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="signup-btn">
                    <a href="/signup">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Sign up</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var Layout = React.createClass({
    render() {
        console.log("layout props");
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div id="review-web">
                <header className="header">
                    <UserMenu />
                </header>
                <div>
                    <RouteHandler path={ this.props.path } />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = Layout;
```

Project structure

[image]

Comment: What output do you get when you run webpack?

Comment: @Jordan here is my package.json: http://dpaste.com/0VZTM2A  When I run webpack (npm start or npm run start) I do not get any errors. My page loads as if no style sheets have been included

Comment: Okay, but what output do you get when you run webpack?

Comment: Also, style-loader *should* inject a `<link ref="stylesheet" ...>` tag into your document, and your browser should download the corresponding `.css` file to which it refers. Inspect the DOM to see if any `<link>` tags appear, and look at the Network tab to see if any `.css` files are being requested.

Comment: @Jordan here ya go: http://dpaste.com/2QDZYQ5

Comment: @Jordan did not know that! I checked my network tab and developer tools and did not see any of those =/

Comment: Try adding the `debug: true` option to your webpack config. You should be getting more output than that—although I'm not familiar with nodemon; maybe it redirects output somewhere?

Comment: @Jordan added `debug: true` but did not see anything different with my output =/ This is what the developer tools is showing me: http://s3.postimg.org/gr1su4uoz/Screen_Shot_2015_08_09_at_4_00_18_PM.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be doing everything fine, except for loading the output from the `ExtractTextPlugin` into your HTML.

When you use `ExtractTextPlugin`, webpack it will bundle `css`, `less` in a separate `bundle.css` file which you have to manually load into your app. **After** you ran the `webpack` CLI from your console, you can expect to find this bundle in a folder inside your `webpackConfig.output.path` folder.

Normally I use `ExtractTextPlugin` only in **production** mode. In development mode, I simply use the `style-loader`, so I can take advantage of the `hot-module-replacement` and so I don't need to run the `webpack` CLI everytime I change styles (I know I could use the webpack-middleware, but I don't want to).

[One of my dev webpack configs](https://github.com/gearz-lab/gearz/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.dev.js)

[One of my prod webpack configs](https://github.com/gearz-lab/gearz/blob/master/webpack/webpack.config.prod.js)

**EDIT**
It was a typo on your [index.less](https://github.com/liondancer/ReviewWeb/blob/master/app/styles/index.less)  file. I fixed that for you on a pull request :)

**EDIT 2**
Ok, here's my last attempt:

Try to add this to your wepback config file:

```
{test: /\.css/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
```

Maybe, just maybe, the LESS loader outputs a temp CSS file that needs to be tested too. I don't know, I would try it.

Then, here's what I would do, in order to reduce to the minimum to test:

- Stop importing in the index.less. I mean, put everything in the index.less and see what happens.
- After you've added the CSS test.. Try replacing LESS by regular CSS, and see if that works.
- Try specifing a publicPath on your webpack config: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration

Comment: I tried `{ test: /\.less$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'}` to exclude `ExtractTextPlugin` but still not working =/

Comment: What is happening? Now the output bundle should be able to inject your style. What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't see any errors which is why this is hard for me to debug =/ Here is my project if youre interested in looking (it's quite small) https://github.com/liondancer/ReviewWeb/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Thank you for spotting the typo. I made a weird noise at the cafe I am at right now after seeing that. I thought this would fix the problem but it did not after making the changes =[

Comment: @Liondancer, God damn it! I've updated my answer with a few more steps you can make. If that doesn't solve it. I'm sorry.. I have to go. Sometimes JavaScript makes me lose hours and hours or work too. :( Anyway.. When you find the answer, please go back and let me know ok? I'll be curious. Good look.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I really appreciated it! I will try your steps and if that doesn't work once i find the answer I will definitely let you know! Thanks!!

Comment: Tried all your tests but none of them worked. I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: @Liondancer. Too bad it did not work. It seems obvious, but just to make sure you understand what is the right result: Your `public/js/main.js` should have instructions to inject the CSS/LESS into your webpage.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance! I thought that was the case but it's good to have confirmation from someone much more experienced!

Comment: Turns out, I was not injecting my javascript into the HTML page. Your instructions were 100% correct however I needed to have routes that handled (`GET`) the JS. https://github.com/liondancer/ReviewWeb/blob/master/server/index.js